# How to Repeat Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to repeat the countdown timer for example I want the countDownTimer should run for like first 60 seconds(user will choose) then 40 seconds(user will choose) and this should repeat like 3 times(user will choose this number) . But I don't know how to do it.

```
fun startTimer() {

        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(testNumber, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                testNumber = millisUntilFinished
                updateTimer()
            }

            override fun onFinish() {

                countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(testNumber2, 1000) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        testNumber2 = millisUntilFinished
                        updateTimer2()
                    }

                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    override fun onFinish() {

                    }
                }.start()
            }
        }.start()

        timerRunning = true
        stopButton.text = "PAUSE"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with "for loop", You just have to check the number given by the user.

Comment: for loop is not working, please share the code if it is worlking in yours

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun counter(repeatCount: Int, second: Long, callback: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    object: CountDownTimer(second * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            // process
            println("repeatCount: $repeatCount, second: $second, time: $millisUntilFinished")
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            if (repeatCount - 1 > 0) counter(repeatCount - 1, second, callback) else callback?.invoke()
        }

    }.start()
}

// Usage
// repeat 1, second 10
counter(1, 10) { // Finished callback.
    // repeat 3, second 60
    counter(3, 60)
}
```

Example output:

```
I/System.out: repeatCount: 1, second: 10, time: 9924
...
I/System.out: repeatCount: 3, second: 5, time: 5000
...
I/System.out: repeatCount: 2, second: 5, time: 5000
...
I/System.out: repeatCount: 1, second: 5, time: 5000
...
```

Comment: In this example, when it's 1 again, it doesn't repeat, so you can think of it as 0 again.

Comment: But where are different times, like user first choose 60 seconds and 40 seconds so the timer will run 60 seconds and after hitting zero timer will run for 40 seconds and this should repeat 3 times.